# Best way to implement time-sensitive dispatch queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, optimization, queue

So I have a service where I can ask for profile-json of a user by passing in the profileID in the request body. If I need 10 peoples profiles, I pass in 10 profileID, and the server will get back with all 10 profile information. Max count = 20.

So I have added an optimization algorithm that groups a bunch of profileIDs based on user scrolling really fast, or user opening up bunch of profiles in the app, etc... Basically my logic is that I have a dispatch_queue that waits roughly 0.6 seconds and in that time I have an array that collects all profileIDs different views in the app will ask for. After 0.6 seconds, whatever is queued up in the array, i include that in the request body, and send it to server.

**Any better strategies/design patterns that I could use here?**

My implementation looks like this.

```
 ----> call in the main thread <--------



 CXAssert([NSThread isMainThread], @"profileInfoForUsers should be main thread");


        if (!profileIDCacheWaitingToRequest) {
            profileIDCacheWaitingToRequest = [NSMutableArray array];
        }

        if (!profileIDArraySubmittedToTheServer) {
            profileIDArraySubmittedToTheServer = [NSMutableArray array];
        }
        if (!_profile_batch_process_queue) {
            _profile_batch_process_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.gather.chatx.profile.batch.process", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
        }

        NSMutableArray *filteredProfileIDCache = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSString *profileID in users) {
            if (profileID == NULL) {
                continue;
            }

            if (![profileIDArraySubmittedToTheServer containsObject:profileID]) {
                CXDebugLog(@"Not sent to server yet");
                if (![profileIDCacheWaitingToRequest containsObject:profileID]) {
                    CXDebugLog(@"Not added to queue yet yet");
                    [filteredProfileIDCache addObject:[profileID copy]];
                } else {
                    CXDebugLog(@"Already present in the queue, will fire soon");
                }
            } else {
                CXDebugLog(@"Skipping profile download call for %@", profileID);
            }
        }

        if (filteredProfileIDCache.count == 0) {
            CXDebugLog(@"No need for submitting profile to server as we are already waiting on server to return..");
            completion (nil, nil);
            return;
        }

        for (NSString *pid in filteredProfileIDCache) {
            if (profileIDCacheWaitingToRequest.count <= GROUP_PROFILE_MAX_COUNT) {
                [profileIDCacheWaitingToRequest addObject:pid];
            } else {
                CXDebugLog(@"wait next turn. hope the user makes this call.");
                continue;
            }
        }

        CXProdLog(@"Queuing profiles for download...");
        dispatch_async(_profile_batch_process_queue, ^{
            // this block will keep executing once its a serial queue..

            /////// SLEEP this thread, and wait for 0.6 seconds


            sleep(0.6);


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                if (profileIDCacheWaitingToRequest.count == 0) {
                    completion (nil, nil);
                    return ;
                }

                NSArray *profileIDsToRequest = [profileIDCacheWaitingToRequest copy];
                [profileIDArraySubmittedToTheServer addObjectsFromArray:profileIDsToRequest];

                CXProdLog(@"Fetching profiles from server with count %lu", (unsigned long)profileIDsToRequest.count);

                if (profileIDsToRequest.count > GROUP_PROFILE_MAX_COUNT) {
                    CXDebugLog(@"We are exceeding the count here");
                    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:profileIDsToRequest];
                    NSUInteger totalNumberOfObjectsToRemove = profileIDsToRequest.count - GROUP_PROFILE_MAX_COUNT;

                    for (int i = 0; i < totalNumberOfObjectsToRemove; i ++) {
                        [array removeLastObject];
                    }

                    profileIDsToRequest = array;
                }

                [CXDownloader downloadProfileForUsers:profileIDsToRequest sessionKey:self.sessionKey completion:^(NSDictionary *profileData, NSError *error) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [profileIDArraySubmittedToTheServer removeAllObjects];
                        if (profileData) {
                           ....
                        }
                        else {
                            ....
                        }

                    });
                }];

                [profileIDCacheWaitingToRequest removeAllObjects];
            });

        });
```

Comment: I couldn't get the logic behind opening a background thread, then sleep, then go back to main thread? Why don't you put all of your code in background thread, and leave the main thread part as is. After all, your code will run synchronically in the background thread...

Comment: I can't put everything in the background thread. When the thread is sleeping for 0.6 seconds, I still want something to process all incoming request to get profileIds

Comment: If you will put all code (except the main thread gcd) it should not prevent from you to process incoming requests... where the incoming requests comes from?

Comment: The key here is the sleep (0.6) code. That thread will sleep to fill up the array and then process it.  Incoming requests can come from anywhere/anylayer. This where everything gets compiled

Comment: The first part of the code will finish synchronically on main thread right before the sleep begins in the background thread. So the 0.6 seconds in your code does nothing but delaying the second part of the code. It does not let anything time to finish...